# Unique fixed point of a contraction defined on a closed ball which maps the boundary back into the ball

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $r > 0$, $A: K_r(X) \rightarrow X$ a contraction (where $K_r(X)$ is the closed ball of radius $r$ and center $0$ in $X$), with contraction constant $0<q<1$, which also fulfills $A(S_r(X)) \subseteq K_r(X)$ (where $S_r(X)$ is the boundary of $K_r(X)$).

Then there exists a unique fixed point of $A$ in $K_r(X)$.

Comment: If the norm has the property that $\lVert \rho(x) - \rho(y)\rVert \leqslant \lVert x-y\rVert$ for all $x,y$, then Banach's theorem applied to $A\circ\rho$ or $\rho\circ A$ yields the result.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is true. But I wonder if I need this as an extra prerequiste. It is possible to prove the finite-dim case without. Maybe it also works  in the infinite-dim case? Unfortunatly $\rho$ does not have this property in any norm...

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks to your advice I managed to solve the problem if $X$ is a Hilbert space.

Comment: I expect that $\rho$ is non-expanding also in uniformly convex spaces, but the proof may be rather messy. I don't know whether attempting to prove that is worth it, there ought to be a general proof, I think.

Comment: One of my coeds said he solved it but he would not show me his whole solution. He told me to disect the operator $Bx = \frac{x  + Ax}{2}$. I can see that every fixed point of $B$ is one of $A$ and that $B$ is a contraction but why should $B$ map $K_{r}(x)$ to $K_{r}(X)$ if I do not know this about $A$...

Comment: Indeed, if $A$ doesn't map $K_r(X)$ to itself, then $B$ need not either. Still, it maps $K_r(X)$ closer to itself than $A$, so it may be worth investigating.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I might have finally found the solution. Maybe you could be so kind to look at it.

Comment: In the last calculation, you need $A\left(\frac{r}{\lVert x\rVert}x\right),$ not $A\frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert}$. That's probably just a slip in the write-up here. Good work.

Comment: Ah, you are absolutly right! Thank you very much for checking.

Comment: Wow! wow! great. You are so smart. Can you share your  intuitive ideas about the selection of the map $\frac{x+Ax}{2}$? Which kind of facts helped you to choose such a map? Your working experience invaluable for me.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Chellapillai: I tried to answer your question in the answer post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has a question come up concerning my solution of the original question. To answer it would be too much for a comment. I therefore decided to split up the original post.

---

## First Steps

To show uniqueness of the fixed point is simple, since $A$ is a contraction. Assume that $x^*$ and $x^{**}$ are two distinct fixed points of $A$. It then follows that
$$
\|x^* - x^{**}\| = \|Ax^* - Ax^{**}\| \leq q\|x^* - x^{**}\|
$$
and therefore $q \geq 1$, which is a contradiction.

Before I arrived at the final solution for existence I found two intermediate results.

1) Solution for **finite dimensional Banach spaces**

Let $X$ be a finite dimensional Banach space. We then define
$$
\rho: X \rightarrow K_r(X), \rho(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x &\text{ if } x \in K_r(X)\\
r\frac{x}{\|x\|} &\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
This mapping is also called the *radial retraction* of $X$ to $K_{r}(X)$ and it is continuous.

Since $A$ is a contraction, $A$ is also continuous. We therefore know that
$$
\rho \circ A: K_r(X) \rightarrow K_r(X)
$$
is continuous. Since we are in a finite dimensional Banach space the operator $\rho \circ A$ has a fixed point $x^* \in K_r(X)$, which follows from *Brouwer's fixed point theorem*.

It now remains to show that this is also a fixed point of $A$. Here we will use the second assumption about the boundary. Assume that $\|Ax^*\| > r$. Then
$$
x^* = (\rho \circ A)(x^*) = r \frac{Ax^*}{\|Ax^*\|} \in S_r(X)
$$
and therefore $Ax^* = \frac{\|Ax^*\|}{r} x^* \not \in K_r(X)$. This is a contradiction to $A(S_r(X)) \subseteq K_r(X)$ and therefore $\|Ax^*\| \leq r$. But then
$$
x^* = \rho(Ax^*) = Ax^*
$$
and we found a fixed point of $A$.

2) Solution for **Hilbertspaces**

Following the advice by Daniel Fischer I have succeeded in proving, that $\|\rho(x) - \rho(y)\| \leq \|x-y\|$ holds for all $x,y\in X$ **if $X$ is a Hilbertspace**. This is quite a lengthy and technical argument involving several cases and the polarisation identity.

Once we know this we can easily see that $\rho \circ A$ is a contraction which maps $K_{r}(X)$ to itself. It therefore has a fixed point by *Banach's fixed point theorem* and just as in the finite dimensional case we can show that it has to be a fixed point of $A$.

This seemed like a good idea at first, but it is a bit messy and I did not want to pursue it any further. It is also questionable if it works for an arbitrary Banach space. Daniel Fischer assumed that it might work for all *uniformly convex spaces* but I did not check that.

---

## General Solution

I then got advice to dissect the operator
$$
Bx = \frac{x + Ax}{2}
$$
which finally led to the

3) Solution for **arbitrary Banach spaces**

One can see that every fixed point of $B$ is a fixed point of $A$ and for $x, y \in K_{r}(X)$ we have
$$
\|Bx - By\| = \|\frac{1}{2}(x - y) + \frac{1}{2}(Ax - Ay)\| \leq \frac{1}{2}\|x - y\| + \frac{1}{2}\|Ax - Ay\| \leq \frac{1 + q}{2}\|x - y\|,
$$
so $B$ is a contraction. It remains to show that $B(K_{r}(X)) \subseteq K_{r}(x)$.

If we assume $X \neq \{0\}$ then there always exists $x \in S_{r}(X)$. We then have for $0 \in K_{r}(X)$ that
$$
\|A0\| = \|A0 - Ax + Ax\| \leq \|A0 - Ax\| + \|Ax\| \leq q\|x\| + \|Ax\| \leq r(q + 1) \leq 2r.
$$
Here I used the fact that $A(S_{r}(X)) \subseteq K_{r}(X)$.

We then get
$$
\|B0\| = \left\|\frac{A0}{2}\right\| \leq r
$$
as well as for any $0 \neq x \in K_{r}(X)$
$$\begin{align}
\|Bx\| &= \left\|\frac{x + Ax - A\left(\frac{r}{\|x\|}x\right) + A\left(\frac{r}{\|x\|}x\right)}{2}\right\| \leq\\ 
    &\leq \frac{1}{2}\|x\| + \frac{1}{2}\left\|Ax - A\left(\frac{r}{\|x\|}x\right)\right\| + \frac{1}{2}\left\|A\left(\frac{r}{\|x\|}x\right) \right\| \leq\\
    &\leq \frac{1}{2}\|x\| + \frac{1}{2}q(r - \|x\|) + \frac{1}{2}r =\\
    &= \frac{1}{2}\|x\|(1 - q) + \frac{1}{2}qr + \frac{1}{2}r \leq\\
    &\leq \frac{1}{2}r(1 - q) + \frac{1}{2}qr + \frac{1}{2}r = r
\end{align}
$$

Finally we get $B(K_{r}(X)) \subseteq K_{r}(X)$ and by *Banach's theorem* we now know that $B$ has a fixed point which is also a fixed point of $A$.

---

## Heuristics

I was asked by Chellapillai how I arrived at the idea of dissecting the map
$$
Bx = \frac{x + Ax}{2}.
$$
As said above is this no idea of my own but I also tried to come up with a heuristic afterwards.

It is quite simple to show that $A$ must map $K_{r}(X)$ to $K_{2r}(X)$ (this works quite similar to the case $x = 0$ above. Just use $r\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ instead of arbitrary $x \in S_{r}(X)$.) It is therefore simple to arrive at the idea of dissecting the operator
$$
Bx = \frac{1}{2}Ax.
$$
This is obviously a contraction if $A$ is a contraction and it maps $K_{r}(X)$ back to itself. By *Banach's theorem* it therefore has a fixed a point and therefore must hold that
$$
x^{*} = Bx^{*} = \frac{1}{2}Ax^{*} \Leftrightarrow Ax^{*} = 2x^{*}.
$$
This far I did get before getting advice but I thought it would not lead anywhere. But from there it is actually quite simple to arrive at the right operator. Just look at
$$
\begin{align*}
&Ax^{*} = x^{*} + x^{*}\tag{1}\\
&Ax^{*} + x^{*} = x^{*} + x^{*} \Leftrightarrow\tag{2}\\
&\frac{Ax^{*} + x^{*}}{2} = x^{*}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: A very harmonic argument. Thank you very much for the heuristic explanation.